# Making key bindings of midnight commander like Vim

Tags: binding, mc, vifm

I would like to have hjkl key to go through directories/files of my panel. This is a bit like elinks with hjkl, less with hjkl, or vifm.

Ctrl+ key left to do a sort of alt+i.

Do you know if those shortcuts are possible?

If yes, please would you mind providing some help or examples of a config file?

Answer (score 12):

Check this excellent [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/532784/midnight-commander-doesnt-use-mc-ini-file):

> The configuration is stored in
>
> ```
> $HOME/.config/mc/
> ```
>
> In your case edit the file `$HOME/.config/mc/ini`. You can check which
>   files are actually read in by midnight-commander using `strace`:
>
> ```
> strace -e trace=open -o mclog mc
> ```

I found my key bindings (on Ubuntu 12.04) at `/etc/mc/mc.keymap`

Comment: still in `/etc/mc/mc.keymap` on Ubuntu 20.04. Just look for the `[panel]` section and append `; j`, `; k`, `; h` and `; l` to the lines starting with `Down`, `Up`, `Left` and `Right` respectively. In my case line 90 to 93.

Comment: For Homebrew installation the path would be a bit different: 
`/usr/local/opt/mc/etc/mc/mc.keymap`

Comment: Another path for Homebrew might be: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/midnight-commander/4.8.29_1/etc/mc`

Answer (score 2):

looking for the same info btw. I want to completely config my mc keybindings. Hope someone comes along...

fwiw I found this:

> 6.1.1 The Default Key Bindings Suck!

```
>Problem    B_alertblock
>The default key bindings suck! I want to change them!
>
>Solution    B_alertblock
>Despite what the Internet tells you, with a recent enough
>Midnight Commander, one can change the key bindings.
>
>Quip    B_block
>But you'll need a PhD to figure out how.
```

>

> Source: http://www.nawaz.org/media/docs/mc/mc.html